# How to deal with signals in process statements

Tags: vhdl

I have a cable connection with an external device that sends serial data to my FPGA. I pass a clock signal along one of the wires inside the cable. On each clock signal the device sends a bit to my FPGA.

Every time I receive 16 bits, I have to tell the device it has to send another 16 bits. I do this by setting another wire (named `LOAD`) within the cable.

```
architecture Connection of main is
begin
    process (OnboardClock)
       variable bitIndex : Integer := 0;
  begin
       if rising_edge(OnboardClock) then

            -- Do something with DATA
            -- Loop till bit index is 16
            -- At index 16, set LOAD to 1
            -- At index 0, unset LOAD to 0 again

            bitIndex := bitIndex + 1;
       end if;
    end process;
end architecture Connection;
```

Now the catch is that `LOAD` is a signal type, so if I use the statement

```
LOAD <= '1'
```

`LOAD` will be scheduled to process later, i.e. it isn't executed in a sequential  order like the other statements within the process. Clearly, my program logic would've been a simple loop if `LOAD` was a variable type, but it isn't...

How can I deal with this in a decent way? Do I have to waste an extra *iteration* to set `LOAD` back to 0?

Comment: If you are genuinely counting to 16 and *then* 0 you are already introducing an extra cycle - that is a modulo-17 counter. So you probably want to rethink your counting loop anyway. (I would make bitIndex a limited-range integer and an explicit modulo counter, `bitIndex := bitIndex + 1 mod 16;` Martin's answer may not be "the common" approach but it's certainly a pretty normal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `LOAD` to high just one cycle earlier, that is, when `bitIndex` is 15. Then reset `LOAD` to low again when `bitIndex` is 16.

Comment: This is indeed a solution I imagined, but because of my inexperience in VHDL I thought there might be a better solution rather than adapting the program logic to deal with signals. Would you say this is the common approach?

Comment: @user1534664, this is very common.  if the logic is complicated enough, it might require a state machine.  but for simple stuff like this, a counter is fine.

Comment: @user1534664 A counter is the simplest state machine. So why not use it where appropiate. I am rarely using variables in my processes because one cannot include them in the waveform of most simulators. Thus, they are hard to debug. I use variables sometimes in my testbenches.

Comment: Plus, if the counter is a signal not a variable, you can use its value outside the process in a concurrent statement such as `Load <= '1' when counter=16 else '0';` I prefer Martin's approach because I want clean signal timings for `Load` and that means a register, but many people don't see it that way,